# How to get the character at the current position using C program?

Tags: c, file-io, fseek

I am trying to write a C program to get the character in the file which is ofset by some bytes, lets say three as below

```
fseek(fp,3,SEEK_CUR);
```

I wish to print the character which that particular byte represents. For example if my file contains something like below,I need to print every third character.

```
//reading from file//
```

The problem is that after using a `while` loop I am not able to print the desired result. The first character which gets printed is the fourth character instead of third.

```
while(fp!=EOF)
{
    fseek(fp,3,SEEK_CUR);
    ch = fgetc (fp);
    printf("%c",ch);
}
```

Can you please help me in understanding what is the mistake with this. Thanks!

Comment: `fp != EOF` is bollocks.

Comment: `fp != EOF` must have made your compiler give a warning (you cannot compare a pointer and an int). Pay attention to compiler warnings, treat them as errors.

Comment: @pmg Thanks for your advice. I am still in learning phase and will take care in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fgetc` moves the file offset by one. Try the following:

```
fseek(fp,3,SEEK_CUR);
while(fp!=EOF)
{
    ch = fgetc (fp); // moves offset by 1
    fseek(fp,2,SEEK_CUR); // moves offset by another 2
    printf("%c",ch);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

fgetc also advances the file pointer by one character.  So each iteration of your loop is advancing the file pointer by a total of 4 characters.  For your purposes, it sounds like you just want to change the 3 to a 2: `fseek(fp,2,SEEK_CUR);`